# Poisson Equation in a Rectangle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, eigenfunctions

The problem is to solve
$$\Delta\phi=\frac \lambda {\varepsilon_0}\delta(x-x',y-y')\quad;\quad
\phi(0,y)=\phi(a,y)=\phi(x,0)=\phi(x,b)=0.$$

My idea was to try and represent the RHS as a series of eigenfunctions of $\Delta$, which will be denoted by $\phi_{n,m}$.

My problem is that the given solution has one series, and my solution ends up with two. I don't see what I've done wrong.

#### My solution:

I found $\phi_{n,m}$ by separation of variables:

$$\Delta\phi=-k^2\phi\,\,\,;\,\,\,\phi(0,y)=\phi(a,y)=\phi(x,0)=\phi(x,b)=0\\\,\\
X''Y+XY''=-k^2XY\\\,\\
\therefore\,\,\dfrac{X''}{X}=-p\quad\dfrac{Y''}{Y}=-q\quad p^2+q^2=k^2$$

Solving these ODEs with the boundary condition yields
\begin{gather*}
X_n = \sin(p_n x) \quad Y_m = \sin(q_m y) \qquad p_n=\frac{n\pi}a \quad q_m=\frac{m\pi}b\\
\therefore\phi_{n,m}=\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}ax\right)\sin\left(\frac {m\pi}b y\right)
\end{gather*}
Due to completeness
$$\phi=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty \beta_{n,m}\phi_{n,m} \quad
\beta_{n,m}=\frac{\langle\phi,\phi_{n,m}\rangle}{\langle\phi_{n,m},\phi_{n,m}\rangle}$$
with the inner product
$$\langle f, g\rangle \equiv \int_0^a\!\!\int_0^b\!\! fg\,dx\,dy$$

Under the assumption that eigenfunction expansion formally works for $\delta$ as well, and that term-by-term differentiation holds:
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta\phi
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty \beta_{n,m}\Delta\phi_{n,m} \\
&= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty k_{n,m}^2 \beta_{n,m}\phi_{n,m} \\
&= \frac{4\lambda}{\varepsilon_0 a b}
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}a x'\right)
   \sin\left(\frac{m\pi}b y'\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}a x\right)
   \sin\left(\frac{m\pi}a y\right)
\end{aligned}\\
\therefore \beta_{n,m} = \frac{-4\lambda\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}a x'\right)
\sin\left(\frac{m\pi}b y'\right)}
{ab\varepsilon_0\left[ \left(\frac{n\pi}a\right)^2  \left(\frac{m\pi}b\right)^2\right]}
\end{gather*}

The solution, however, was given as
$$\phi(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-4\lambda \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}a x'\right) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}b y'\right)}
{ab\varepsilon_0 \left[\left(\frac{n\pi} a\right)^2 \left(\frac{n\pi}b\right)^2\right]}
\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}a x\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}b y\right)$$

What have I done wrong? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I've edited your question to include your attempted solution inline. Since you do not yet have enough reputation for posting inline graphics, if you need to edit the question again, please flag for moderator attention to help you keep the image displayed.

Comment: I've edited your question to use MathJax. I'm sorry you never got an answer. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Nope. It was part of a problem in an engineering class and the lecturer wasn't interested in discussing "the number of sigmas".. haha

Comment: @Sai You can always start a bounty to double your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Is there perhaps something that really needs to be added to my question?

Comment: All questions should be solved in a timely manner :/.